# How to call other class in JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing, methods

I got one `JMenuItem` with start code.  How can I get when I click one icon that the code will start?

```
private void jMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
  String color="blue";
}

private void IconActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  // here i dont know how start JmenuItem when i click on it
  get.jMenuItemActionPerformed; 
}
```

Comment: do you mean calling `jMenuItemActionPerformed(evt);` by hand (although `evt` might not be appropriate any more) ?

Comment: yes i mean calling jMenuItemActionPerformed(evt);

Comment: `String color="blue";` General tip: use instead something like `Color color=Color.BLUE;` if that is actually meant to represent a color.
BTW - even with the comment, your questions still makes little or no sense to me. But I'll take a stab.  Factor that code line in my comment out to a method of it's own.  Call the method from wherever needed.

Comment: I just noticed that the fist method actually achieves nothing.  It creates a local variable that is not used & goes out of scope after the end of the method.

Comment: i got code 100 lines long, and i want on JButon call jMenuItem if is that posible or is there any other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you haven't added an `ActionListener` to your `JMenuItem`. An `ActionListener` waits until some action is performed (e.g. clicking) on a GUI component, then calls some code. For example:

```
JMenuItem myMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Hello");
myMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello button clicked!"); // or call some other method
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way or simply a **workaround** but you that menu item should be in your main frame. So you can climb up the component hierarchy to get its containers/parent till the class does not match your frames class. Once available you can get its listeners and fire the event.

Again I feel its a workaround that popped in my head and you can get the code running till you get the solution.